# Sqoop support for json data type for a table field?

Tags: json, postgresql, hdfs, sqoop

I am trying to import tables from Postgresql to HDFS, using Sqoop. It works fine. But when I try to import a table, where one of the fields is of json type, it shows the error:

```
ERROR orm.ClassWriter: Cannot resolve SQL type 1111
```

It seems like Sqoop does not support json as data types for table fields. Any idea if there is a solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:5432/iAtlas --table msg02 --username aaaa.bbbbb --password ccccc --schema tracking --map-column-java wsresp=String --map-column-hive wsresp=STRING
```

add --map-column-hive option also, using --map-column-java we are mapping sql type to java type then using --map-column-hive will map it to hive type

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the similar error. Was able to resolve it by using --map-column-java option in sqoop import command. Map the json type to String at the time of import like:

--map-column-java wsresp=String

Comment: I tried this but again the same error. The code I tried: sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:5432/iAtlas
 --table msg02 --username aaaa.bbbbb --password ccccc -- --schema tracking --map-column-java wsresp=String. So I added your code at the end, is this correct?

Comment: Try this:

sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:5432/iAtlas --table msg02 --username aaaa.bbbbb --password ccccc --schema tracking --map-column-java wsresp=String --map-column-hive wsresp=STRING

add --map-column-hive option also, using --map-column-java we are mapping sql type to java type then using --map-column-hive will map it to hive type

Comment: I tried this but again got "Cannot resolve SQL type 1111" error

Comment: Should I specify somehow which column should be mapped? Is this --map-column-java with no blanks inside? Is the keyword wsresp spelled correctly?

Comment: I specified the column: --map-column-java Accumulators=String, but again the same error

Comment: In fact not the same error but it only closes (gives no explanations)

Comment: Add this two options at the end of your commad. --map-column-java Accumulators=String  --map-column-hive Accumulators=STRING    I am assuming that Accumulators is your column name. you have to specify --map-column-java and --map-column-hive also.

Comment: Yes I did so, but it simply closes now, doesn't give any error nor processes anything. It only prints 1 and exits.

Comment: Please share the exact command that you are running. I will try it on my end.

Comment: sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test --table tmp_calamp_msg02 --username ada.kada --password adakada -- --schema tmp_calamp_tracking  --map-column-java Accumulators=String --map-column-hive Accumulators=String